# How can I enable code coverage in Xcode 14.3? (It appears different from other versions)

Tags: xcode, code-coverage

Normally I would follow [these steps](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-nqz9uuL-AhUFjLAFHVJ7AYcQFnoECAwQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.browserstack.com%2Fguide%2Fxcode-code-coverage%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DYou%2520will%2520start%2520by%2520turning%2Cselect%2520the%2520Code%2520Coverage%2520box.&usg=AOvVaw3wB-u139TRNeZ1C1AM2r1o).  Basically I woult tap on my scheme, then edit, then Test, then I'd have a nice neat enable code coverage box I can tick.  However, with 14.3, I don't see the info | options etc tabs, instead I see this view.  And enable code coverage isn't there. Usually, it would be between Build configuration and Debugger.

14.3

[image]

Old view:
[image]

I don't see show code coverage here either:

[image]

Comment: I created my own custom scheme.  When I switched to the default scheme, code coverage was available.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Enabling Code Coverage has moved to [Test Plan](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/organizing-tests-to-improve-feedback) configuration which is designed to manage your tests and was introduced in Xcode 11 at [WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413/).

Do the following steps to enable it:

1. Press Command + Option + u to bring the Edit Scheme window

[image]

2. Hover over the Autocreated test plan to show the disclosure button and click it.

[image]

3. Go to the Configuration tab :

   [image]
4. Find Code Coverage and enable it :

[image]

Comment: This occurred again for me, and this answer was the only one to fix it.

Comment: @igor-muzyka did you save it? Command S

Answer (score 5):

You can enable it on the test plans configuration. Go to the Test navigator. Click on the "Test Plan" dropdown and then select "Edit test plan"

[image]

You will be able to update the shared configs of your test plans, including conde coverage enabling:
[image]

Comment: This was on by default for me but doesn't provide any test coverage

Answer (score 4):

Once you successfully turn on code coverage (as described by the answers above), do the following:

1. Run your tests.
2. Right-click on a test.
3. Choose "Jump to Report

[image]

5. Select Test Example Test (your app name)

[image]

6. From the drop down, choose "Coverage"

[image]

7. View the report.

[image: -]

Answer (score 1):

Once you turn on the code coverage, check that your file .xctestplan has been created and added to your project. Then on the last tab of left panel of Xcode, the 'Show the report navigator', once your test has been launched you should have a 'coverage' line that will give you access of all your coverage
[xcode-screenshot-code-coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEYFL.png)

Comment: This is answer for my case, any others was not helpful. I migrated my project from native Xcode configurations to the Tuist and it broke test coverage calculation.

Answer (score 1):

`Edit your schema` -> `Test Plan` as suggested by @Mehdi Ijadnazar more above and then:

1. Enable Code Coverage
   [image]
2. Make sure that .xctestplan has been created.
   [image]
3. Verify the file is in your project.
   [image]
4. Run tests
   [image]